# Image Description Tooltips

Tags: feature-request

Could the image description text be made into a tooltip?

Currently the description you put before specifying the image url (`![description][image_url]`) only appears while the image is loading.

It would be nice if that text also appeared as a tooltip when hovering over the image, this would give more incentive to fill in those descriptions too.

Answer (score 4):

This has actually already been asked on [math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10726):

> Just add hover text in parentheses:
>
> ```
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/..... (hover text)
> ```
>
> or in quotation marks:
>
> ```
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/..... "hover text"
> ```

---

> There's a good reason to have alt-text and hover-text as separate
>   attributes: one is intended for users who don't see the image, the
>   other for those who do.

So

```
![][1]

[1]: http://download.blender.org/institute/BlenderSocketLogo.png (That's a nice picture..)
```

or

```
![][1]

[1]: http://download.blender.org/institute/BlenderSocketLogo.png "That's a nice picture.."
```

gives:

http://download.blender.org/institute/BlenderSocketLogo.png

---

This works nicely, but I'm still wondering if perhaps having the tooltip default to the alternate text (unless of course if the description text is entirely white space, null, or equal to `enter image description here`) is something worth doing anyway.

Most of the time when you do fill out the image description it's something that would make at least some sense as both a tooltip and alternate text.

If you still want them to be separate, you could specify a separate tooltip with the method mentioned above, which would override the image description tooltip. (yet keep the image description as the alternate text)

If you really don't want the tooltip for some reason you could override it by adding a tooltip consisting of whitespace (these don't get rendered it seems)

It might be nice to have tooltips more accessible, since in most cases (definitely not all) the alternate text only appears for a tiny amount of time then is invisible, replaced by the image. This gives very little incentive to fill out those descriptions because hardly anyone will even read them.

If the descriptions were made into tooltips by default (with the options above, to disable to separate them) then more users would fill it in with a quick description of what the image is which would be displayed as alternate text and a tooltip without any further fuss. (for filling with more detailed information, one should probably limit that to the tooltip only and put a short description of the image as alternate text)